# how to connect Matlab with PHP

Tags: php, matlab

I want to connect Matlab with php (server) for image processing on fly. 
I'm getting this error

```
An unexpected exception has been detected in native code outside the VM.
Unexpected Signal : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) occurred at PC=0x789DFE73
Function=inPushCheckpoint+0xB3
Library=C:\MATLAB701\bin\win32\m_interpreter.dll
```

when I am trying to execute your given code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article out [Using MATLAB with PHP](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/php_and_matlab).

It's not about image processing, but it should give you the basics to start working on your problem. If that's not what you were looking for, can you give more details?

Comment: thank u for your kindly help.. i want to perform OCR (Optical Character Recognizance) on web. For this i have to connect PHP with Matlab or Mysql with matlab.

Comment: i have edited my question with error m getting after executing your given code

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy alternative solution

open matlab then in command window type mbuild -setup

then install the lcc-compiler

after that in open command prompt then go to your matlab programme directory . the programme you want to connect with php . then type mcc -m yourprograme.m in command prompt and wait for a while. after that you will get a exe file one your directory. and then type

yourprogramme.exe > output.txt

and by file_get_contains("output.txt");

you will get the output in the php